# Google Play Core App Quality Test GP-2

Tags: android, google-play

I am just finishing development of my first app for Android.  I am setting up the app's page in Google Play and am running through the quality tests documented [here](http://developer.android.com/distribute/essentials/quality/core.html#gp)

My question is about test GP-2 (Download your feature graphic and screenshots and scale them down to match the display sizes on the devices and form factors you are targeting.)

What does this mean?  The feature graphic is required to be a fixed size (1024x500) no more no less.  What would I scale it down to?  Same question for screenshots.  Lastly, what would I do with the scaled down graphics - i.e. where would I upload them?.

I think there is probably a simple answer for this as the search engines provided no help, I thought I would ask here for a better explanation of this requirement as a next step.